# Automatically unlock the lock screen when the correct PIN is entered

Tags: lock-screens

On my Motorola Droid X2, I have to enter the PIN and then hit the arrow-like return button. On my iPod Touch, if I type the 4 digit passcode, it'll unlock as soon as I hit that fourth digit.

Is there any way to have the lock-screen unlock as soon as I enter the correct code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because unlike the iPhone/iPod Touch, the unlock PIN can be longer than 4 digits. Android allows between 4 and 16 digits for the lock screen. Since it is "unknown" what the length of your PIN is, you have to press OK to indicate "you are done".

Comment: Ahh. Too bad it just doesn't compare the hashes on each tap.

Comment: iPhone has the same behavior above but also offers a 4 and 6 key lock.  No reason Android couldn't also offer both.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the alternate lock types unlock immediately.

The built-in Android pattern lock, where you do a "join the dots" between the nine dots displayed on the screen unlocks immediately your finger lifts off the screen (presuming that you've got the pattern right).

Comment: he's talking about the PIN code..

Comment: @Power Clearly yes, and I'm talking about alternates to the PIN code that do what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the question is old but remains valid for current time as well, so I'm answering keeping currently relevant Android versions in mind.

If your Android is rooted, has a compatible Xposed Framework<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> installed, then provided that your Android can run GravityBox Xposed module, the latter can solve the problem.

#### Instructions:

1. Install GravityBox relevant to your Android version, enable the module under Xposed Installer app and reboot the device.
2. Launch GravityBox, go to *Lockscreen tweaks* and enable *Quick unlock*. Once you enable it, the previously grayed out entry named *PIN length* would become available for tweak. Set it to the length your current PIN/Password consists of.

Changes would take place immediately.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Official GravityBox versions:

- For Android Jelly Bean: [GravityBox [JB]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox)
- For Android KitKat: [GravityBox [KK]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox)
- For Android Lollipop: [GravityBox [LP]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox)
- For Android Marshmallow: [GravityBox [MM]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Xposed Framework: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Handcent SMS has a lockscreen with PIN input that also has similar functionality. Entering the correct code auto unlocks when the last correct digit is entered without the need to press OK.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 10, you didn't have to press the arrow key for PIN code, just lift your finger after the 4th button push, and it auto signs in.

When I bought Alcatel 1B burner phones, they came with Android 10 stock and I noticed that feature right away and the option to not briefly show password letters when entering passwords.

Now on Android 11, you have to push the continue arrow again after the PIN code.

Answer (score 1):

"Auto-confirm unlock" became part of Android 14 (and AOSP), see [Settings change 4c8ad8f](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/4c8ad8f91124a10e154bcf8cf8bbd6504222658e)

> [Auto Pin Confirm]: Changes to allow PIN auto confirm feature to be controllable by the user

for how to reach the setting, see the [screenshot](https://beebom.com/best-android-14-features/#h-10-auto-confirm-unlock) in the article.

Answer (score 0):

On OnePlus/OxygenOS phones, this setting can be changed when changing the PIN itself. So if you want to switch to auto-enter versus manual enter, do the procedure for changing the PIN and you will have a checkbox while entering the PIN to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get unlocked without tapping "OK" soon as you finish your PIN. Go to Security settings and on PIN code, there will be an option saying "Confirm PIN without tapping OK". Check that and you are good to go.

Comment: Based on searching, looks like this feature with this particular label is only available on Samsung devices.

Answer (score -1):

The Cyanogenmod (checked in CM10) lock screen also allows to unlock as soon as you enter the correct code.

Comment: That's a nice feature of CyanogenMod. But the OP doesn't have CyanogenMod installed, so it won't help him specifically.

Comment: This close to what I was looking for.  I updated to CM13 and can no longer find this option.

Comment: CM 11 is missing this feature after Marshmallow update :(